# In IntelliJ IDEA Maven gets the external library according to .pom but trying to compile gives "package does not exist"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, package

I'm simply trying to get one external library into use for a test project in IntelliJ IDEA. I have a pom file, and doing "Reimport" gives the external library as shown in the "dependencies" section of the .pom file. But when I try to import that package, it just gives me compiler error that the package doesn't exist.

What gives? What step am I missing? If the project has a .pom file that gives a specific external library, shouldn't that be available for the project? Or does it matter what I have as "groupid" or "artifactId"?

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay. I found it out. It wasn't as I described. Rather the library had changed its package name and that's why it couldn't be imported.